ASP.NET 8.0 Core App 2024 getting error: Exception System.PlatformNotSupportedException: EventLog access is not supported on this platform
Update.
So when running the application from the Debug directory unser the project in Visual Studio. it works.  In the same exact command prompt and changing to the installation directory, I get the error.
Also performed a winmerge against the 2 directories, they are identical.
This makes no sense
Details: project is running on Windows 11. Running from Visual Studio 2022, everything is working. Using Microsoft Installer project to deploy on same machine, I get the error mentioned in the title.
In project file, targeted framework is:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>

Here is a screenshot of project properties:
I followed all recommended items including adding Window Compatibility, downgrading EventLog and Hosting to 6.0.0.0, etc nothing seems to work. Also tried running the dll via dotnet with same problem.
Added Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog nuget package and changed configuration to use this. Nothing is working

Please share detailed steps how to reproduce the issue. One more thing,  you are using win7 ?Because I find this net8.0-windows7.0.

And please also share the .csproj file, many thanks~
